# as3 convert a string to an arbitrary number

Tags: actionscript-3, string, numbers

I want to seed a number generator using a string input. What function would be best for simply turning the string into a number to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is some simple algorithm of your creation, to avoid possible hacks.
One method would be to add the value of each character using charCodeAt(),

```
function generateSeed(input:String):Number {
    var r:Number = 0;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        r += input.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Also, depending on the required security, you can also try using MD5 or SHA-1.

Answer (score 1):

If you're guaranteed that the input will be a number, you can simply cast it to a number from string through Number("4") 
ie.

```
var stringInput:String = "15"; // or wherever you're getting the input from
var seed:Number = Number(stringInput);
```

Comment: thanks, although I didn't explain my question very well - the input will almost never actually be a number, but random text instead.